# The best approach to manage dev accounts for chatbots apps of Facebook

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-es, facebook-chatbot

I made a chatbot for the page of my business on Facebook, using my own accounts and without problem because I am the administrator.

But I want to create more chabots for other businesses that have their Facebook page.

I realized that it is necessary that I be an administrator on the page of the other business, in order to create the token and webhooks, and connect with dialogflow, etc.

Is there a way to do this? I mean that if I must choose one of these actions:

1. That I become an adminsitrator of the facebook page of the other business, and use my own facebook development account to create the app and develop everything.
2. Create a developer account for the current administrator of the other business's Facebook page, control and create everything from their account and just add my developer account.
3. Another option you recommend.

I ask all this because due to the policy of revision of application where they ask you to verify your business, I do not know what is the best way, if the application should be in my development account or better a development account by business.

I think it's very tedious to be creating a development account for each business. I would like to be able to handle everything from my only development account, but I need the administrator's permission of the facebook pages of each business.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is implement FB Login to allow the Page Admin to grant you pages_messaging and manage_pages permissions. This will allow you to generate tokens and send messages on behalf of the page without being a Page Admin.